# Test Class for Visualforce Controller Test Class Coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, code-coverage

I have a simple Visualforce page with a simple controller as follows

```
public class EDU_CustomController_Getter {

 private String sortOrder = 'LastName';

//This is the getter method used to parse values from Apex Controller to Visualforce Page 
public List<Contact> getContacts() {

//List<Contact> results = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Title, Email FROM CONTACT ORDER BY = :sortOrder];
List<Contact> results = Database.query(
    'SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Title, Email ' +
    'FROM Contact ' +
    'ORDER BY ' + sortOrder + ' ASC ' +
    'LIMIT 10'
);
return results;
}

public void sortByLastName() {
    this.sortOrder = 'LastName';
}

public void sortByFirstName() {
    this.sortOrder = 'FirstName';
}
}
```

I have the following testclass but I'm only getting 10% code coverage. How can I cover the missing lines? Test Class as follows:

```
@isTest
public class test_EDU_CustomController_Getter {

static testmethod void testContactVisible(){
    Test.startTest();

    Account testAccount = new Account();
    testAccount.Name='Test Account' ;
    insert testAccount;

    Contact testcont = new Contact();
    testcont.FirstName='Test';
    testcont.LastName='Test';
    testcont.Accountid= testAccount.id;       
    insert testcont;

    PageReference myVfPage = Page.EDU_GetterMethods;
    Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage); 

    //construct controller
    EDU_CustomController_Getter controller = new EDU_CustomController_Getter();
    String sortOrder = 'LastName';

    //Test query
    List<Contact> Records = Database.query(
    'SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Title, Email ' +
    'FROM Contact ' +
    'ORDER BY ' + sortOrder + ' ASC ' +
    'LIMIT 10'
);

    Test.stoptest();  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the methods in your controller. The point of a unit test is not to duplicate the code, but actually *test* the code you're trying to cover. Note that *proper* testing of your code will involve at least 2 contacts to make sure the records are sorted correctly.

```
EDU_CustomController_Getter controller = new EDU_CustomController_Getter();
Contact[] records = controller.getRecords();
System.assertEquals(2, records.size(), 'Expected two contacts.');
controller.sortByFirstName();
records = controller.getRecords();
System.assertEquals('Test1', records[0].LastName, 'Expected Test1 to appear first.');
// ... etc ...
```

This code above is only for example; you will need to make the appropriate changes to properly test your code.