# How to get status of a checkbox from visual force page to controller

Tags: apex, parameters, visual

I am trying to show an error message when the checkbox is not checked. How do I pass the checkbox parameter from visualforce page to controller so that I can compare the status of checkbox and display an error message accordingly.

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="showUser">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Program Registration</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <apex:form >
                <apex:pageBlock title="Registration" >
                        <apex:pageMessages />
                <!--    <apex:inputField value="{!event.Authorized_by__c}"/> -->
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                        <apex:inputCheckbox id="mycheckbox" value="{!chkBoxAgree}" required="True"/>Consent Statement here 
                    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!saveRecord}" value="Register"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:form>
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public without sharing class showUser {
    public String userName{set;get;}
    public List<Contact> storeDetails{set;get;}
    public Boolean chkBoxAgree{set;get;}
    public static PageReference saveRecord()  
    { 
        showUser su = new showUser();
        try
        {
                    if (su.chkBoxAgree == false) 
                    {
                        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Please agree to the consent statement'));
                        return null;
                    }       
                    Event_Registrations__c event = new Event_Registrations__c();
                    su.userName= UserInfo.getUserEmail();
                    system.debug(su.userName);
                    su.storeDetails = [select Store__c, AccountId, Account.Name from contact where Email like :su.userName];       
                    system.debug(su.storeDetails);
                    event.Store_No__c = su.storeDetails[0].Store__c;
                    event.Account__c = su.storeDetails[0].AccountId;
                    event.Program_Event__c = 'a1G3D000001Re07UAC';    
                    insert event;
                    Account accountData = [select Id from Account where ID = :event.Account__c limit 1];
                    accountData.Registered_for_MedSask__c = true;
                    update accountData;  
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `su` variable. Get rid of `showUser su = new showUser();` and all the `su.` accesses. The variables bound in your page are directly accessible in your controller. The saveRecord method must not be `static`.

Comment: I removed ```showUser su = new showUser();``` and the ```su.``` But now I am getting variable does not exist error for the all the class variables

Comment: @KiranG I just noticed the method is static. It must not be static in order to access the class variables.

Comment: @KiranG For the unit test, the test method is static, but you will create your controller in the unit test. See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/240339/2984) for an example of how to do that.